# Android Studio ( Logcat Button ) disappear in Flutter

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, dart, logcat

I use Android Studio version 3.6.3 on my macOS Version Catalina, when I run my program use dart programming language inside my android studio, my logcat button is not shown or disappear on my android studio, by the way, I use API 30 for created my app with the dart.

this is my android studio screenshot :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NZ7gS.png)

[image]

how can it be like that, anyone can explain.

Answer (score 1):

you can open up the `LogCat` window by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>6</kbd> on Windows or <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>6</kbd> on Mac.

Or you can click **View > Tool Windows > LogCat**

[image]

After that, your LogCat button will be staying at the bottom like before.

> **UPDATE**

If you still can't find it, click the rectangle bottom in the bottom-left corner:

[image]

Or if it's still doesn't appear, click the **Event Log** at the bottom-right corner.

Let me know if it's helpful

Comment: what kind android studio, are you using

Comment: I have updated my answer. Let me know if it's helpful

Answer (score 0):

Simply, goto **View > Tool Windows > LogCat**

and here's your Logcat window.

Comment: what kind of android studio , are you using it